# Data from table to edit doesnt work mysqli and GET/POST

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli, get

Im not a PHP pro i started php 3 weeks ago my knowledge is low.

My Problem:
In my outdex.php there is table with content read out of my database.
if i click the icon to edit a column i get to edit.php
But it doesnt shown my editable column.

My Code:
outdex.php

```
    <?php 
    require('config/config.inc.php');


$sql = "SELECT id, name, Status, Strasse, Telefon, ProblemBeschreibung, Datum FROM probleme WHERE id = 1 OR id > 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Ausgabe der Daten in einer row
    echo '<table class="bordered"><thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th style="display: none;">ID</th>';
        echo '<th>Name</th>';
        echo '<th>Status</th>';
        echo '<th>Stra&szlig;e</th>';
        echo '<th>Telefon</th>';
        echo '<th>Problembeschreibung</th>';
        echo '<th>Eintragsdatum</th>';
        echo '<th width="36"></th>';
        echo '</tr></thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';
    while($adr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $adr['name'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $adr['Status'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $adr['Strasse'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $adr['Telefon'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $adr['ProblemBeschreibung'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $adr['Datum'] . "</td>
                <td>
                    <div id=\"test\">
                    <div id=\"div1\"><form action='edit.php' method='GET'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" .htmlspecialchars($adr['id'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='name' value='".htmlspecialchars($adr['name'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='Status' value='".htmlspecialchars($adr['Status'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='Strasse' value='".htmlspecialchars($adr['Strasse'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='Telefon' value='".htmlspecialchars($adr['Telefon'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='ProblemBeschreibung' value='".htmlspecialchars($adr['ProblemBeschreibung'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='Datum' value='".htmlspecialchars($adr['Datum'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')."'/>
                        <input type='image' src='edit.png' height='16' width='16' name='edit' value='Bearbeiten' onClick=\"self.location.href='edit.php?=\">
                    </form></div>
                    <div id=\"div2\">
                    <form action='delete.php' method='POST'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . htmlspecialchars($adr['id'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . "'/>
                        <input type='image' src='delete.png' height='16' width='16' name='delete' value='Löschen' onClick=\"self.location.href='delete.php?\">
                    </form></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                </tr>\n";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
} else {
    echo "0 Eintr&auml;ge gefunden<br>Es konnten keine Einträge in der Datenbank gefunden werden.";
}


mysqli_close($db);  
?>
```

My edit.php

```
<table class="bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Strasse</th>
            <th>Telefon</th>
            <th>Problembeschreibung</th>
            <th>Eintragsdatum</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php

    include('config.inc.php');
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    } else {
        die('Bitte eine ?id übergeben');
    }
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM probleme WHERE id = ?");
    $statement->execute(array($id));
    while($row = $statement->fetch()){
        echo "<tr>
            <form method='post' action='edit1.php'>
                <td><input name='id' type='text' value='".$id."'</input></td>
                <td><input name='name' type='text' value='" .$row['name']."'</input></td>
                <td>
                    <select name='Status'>
                        <option>".$row['Status']."</option>
                        <option>FINISHED</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input name='Strasse' type='text' value='".$row['Strasse']."'</input></td>
                <td><input name='Telefon' type='number' value='".$row['Telefon']."'</input></td>
                <td><input name='ProblemBeschreibung' type='text' value='".$row['ProblemBeschreibung']."'</input></td>
                <td>".$row['Datum']."</td>
            </tr>
            </table>";

        echo "
        <input type='submit' value='Absenden' />
        </form>";
    }
?>
```

If I change GET to POST it doesnt work too.
hope you can help me.

Comment: Why not just use `WHERE id >=1`

Comment: outdex.php is working. It shows me my stuff from my database table "probleme".

Comment: Are you getting **$_GET['id']**?

Comment: I guess. I dont get my error message ( if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    } else {
        die('Bitte eine ?id übergeben');
) so I guess i get the id. but it dont show it up

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: No error message. It just dont show me my table which i want to edit. I guess all after :$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM probleme WHERE id = ?");
    $statement->execute(array($id));
    while($row = $statement->fetch()){ doesnt work.